# Why my variables aren't swapping properly?

Tags: assembly, swap, 68000

I was writing code for variable swap in in Motorola 68k Assembly Code. It was not working as intended. I was trying to debug but I simply cannot see where I messed up.

```
VALUE       EQU      $2000
PROG        EQU      $2100
    
            ORG      VALUE
VAR1:       DS.L     1
VAR2:       DS.L     1
     
            ORG      PROG
START:      MOVE.L   VAR1, $210E
            MOVE.L   VAR2, VAR1
            MOVE.L   $210E, VAR2

            END    START
```

First I tried to initialize variable TEMP at $210E but result was the same. After that I tried to initialize TEMP at $2100 but that did not work either.

Comment: You have two `org value`s, doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ErikEidt it still does not work after the change (i edited code just now)

Comment: @ErikEidt i noticed where is the problem. Adress $210E is used for instructions of code. From $2100 to $2111 is where PROG is written. I used part of its memory so it altered what is done. For example if VAR1 = AAAAAAAA and VAR2 = BBBBBBBB. Then output will be VAR1 = BBBBBBBB and VAR2 = BBBBBBB. Because adress' $210E to %2111 will be used by PROG

Comment: Assembler support labels for a reason. It is a bit unclear why you are using the absolute address $210e for temporary storage - Such errors are easily avoidable by using labels - Writing to your code space is even worse (and harder to detect) on later m68k versons that have code and data caches that might not imediately be affected, but hit you even harder at some later point in time.

Comment: Yes, changing the 2nd org value to org prog, then using that code address for a temp variable is problematic!  Could have used $2008 or beyond instead of $210e for temp storage.  But really should use a register instead of memory for such temp storage, i.e. `D0.L`.